# counting sequences with constraints

Tags: combinatorics

For any $m, n\ge0$. Is there a way to count the number of sequences of length $m$ such that 
       $$a_1 =  a_m = 0$$  $$\left | a_{k} - a_{k-1} \right | =1$$ 
$$0\leq a_{k}\leq n$$

Comment: When $m \leq \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$, we're counting [Dyck paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics), which are counted by the Catalan numbers.  When $m > \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$, however, the boundary condition $0 \leq a_k \leq n$ will exclude some of those paths (and the Catalan numbers will be an upper bound).

Answer (score 0):

We can deduce a recurrence. Consider $f(i,j)$ means the number of sequences in the interval $\left[ i, ..., m\right]$ when we have chosen $j$ like the number in the place $i-1$. We want to find $f(2, 0)$ because the constraint $a_1=0$. Then

$$\displaystyle f(i,j)=\sum\limits_{k=max(0,j-1)}^{min(n,j+1)}{f(i+1,k)} - f(i+1,j)$$

we subtract the term $f(i+1,j)$ because we are adding it in the sum. The base case is when $i=m+1$, so

$$f(m+1,0)=1$$
$$f(m+1,k)=0, \space k\ne0$$

because the constraint $a_m=1$.